# Authenicating user using jQuery AJAX not working

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm trying to authenticate a user using AJAX wrapped with jQuery to call a PHP script that queries a MySQL database. I'm NOT familiar with *any* of those technologies but I (sorta) managed to get them working individually, but I can't get the jQuery, AJAX and HTML to work properly.

**[Edit:]** I followed [Trinh Hoang Nhu's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/533738/trinh-hoang-nhu) [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11755248/authenicating-user-using-jquery-ajax-not-working#comment-15607048) and added a `return false;` statement to disable the Submit button. All previous errors fixed, I can't get the object returned by the AJAX right.

### HTML

Here's the HTML snippet I use:

```
<form id="form" method='post'>
    <label>Username:</label>
    <input id="user" name="user" type="text" maxlength="30" required /> <br />
    <label>Password:</label>
    <input id="pass" name="pass" type="password" maxlength="30" required /> <br />
    <input id="url" name="url" type="text" value="<?php echo $_GET['url'] ?>" hidden />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="I'm done">
  </form>
```

### jQuery/AJAX

Here's my jquery code for using AJAX to authenticate a user (sorry if the indenting is messed up because of the tabs):

```
function changeMessage(message) {
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = message; }

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form").submit(function() {
        changeMessage("Checking");
        //check the username exists or not from ajax
        $.post("/stufftothink/php/AJAX/login.php",
                    {user: $("#user").val(), pass: $("#pass").val(), url: $("#url") },
                    function(result) {
                        //if failed
                        if (result === 'false') {
                            changeMessage("Invalid username or password. Check for typos and try again");
                            $("#pass").val(""); }
                        //if authenticated
                        else {
                            changeMessage("Authenticated");
                            window.location.href = result; } 
                    } );
        //to disable the submit button
        return false;
    }   );
} )
```

### PHP

And here's my PHP script that gets called:

```
<?php 
ob_start();
session_start();

$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = md5($_POST['pass']);

mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('stufftothink');

$query = "select * from users where user = '$user' and pass = '$pass'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $i = 1; }

if ($i == 1) {
  $_SESSION['user'] = $user; 
    $invalid_urls = array('register.php', 'login.php');
    $url = $_REQUEST['url']; //not sure whether _GET or _POST
    if (in_array($url, $invalid_urls)) {
        echo '/stufftothink/profile.php'; }
    else {
    echo '/stufftothink/'.$url; }
    }

else {
  echo 'false'; }

mysql_close();
?>
```

### Edit

I've been getting a lot of downvotes on this question. I had accidentally submitted the question without the explanation filled in. I went back to edit it, but when I came back, there were already 4 downvotes. It had barely been a couple of minutes. Am I doing something wrong, or were the first 5 minutes the problem?

Comment: You should provide more details, errors and such...

Comment: Very secure too... IF you are using PHP sessions, you don't need to pass the username/password around! But yes, explain the problem, give what is happening as well as not happening and any errors (if any).

Comment: @Sutuma I had mistakingly submitted it. I later went and clarified it by editing. I don't get all the downvotes. It's barely been a couple of seconds.

Comment: @Brian See my previous comment. I don't know if you had downvoted my question, but if you had, could you please remove it?

Comment: @Brian What does your (first) comment mean?

Comment: Please install firebug and use net module to catch what server return

Comment: @Brian How can I initialize a session before the user logs in?

Comment: @Brian Did you mean my solution _is_ secure, or _not_ secure?

Comment: @TrinhHoangNhu Will Firebug for Chrome do, or do I have to use Firefox?

Comment: To initialize a session just call session_start, you did it right, but you need to catch what server return. May be some error of db

Comment: NOT.... password is plain text for a start.

Comment: @YatharthROCK Chorme is ok, just catch what server return with your ajax call

Comment: @TrinhHoangNhu k, I got Firefox and Firebug installed (Firebug was causing issues in Chrome). I don't get what you mean by the `net module`. There's no such extension and I'm not sure about a net panel either.

Comment: On firebug or inspect element on chrome, you can open console tab (or net/Network tab). When an ajax is called and return, this page can catch its out put and let you see what's happens.

Comment: @TrinhHoangNhu I don't understand the output. Also, the page refreshes every time I click the button (which, considering I'm usning AJAX, shouldn't happen unless I successfully authenticate which is not the case)

Comment: @TrinhHoangNhu I'll give you some screenshots, wait

Comment: on $("#form").submit(function() you have to return false to allow ajax to work and disable form submit by default. Paste the output here

Comment: @TrinhHoangNhu That world. Do you want to create an answer so I can accept it? Or should I answer my question myself?

Comment: Oh wait, I spoke too fast. Now the url returned by the PHP is some object. How do I parse that?

Comment: @Brian I probably shouldn't do this but, can you give this question an upvote? It has been unfairly downvited and now my account has been automatically "suspended" b'coz of too many (only 3, really) "low-quality" questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First if you want to submit form using ajax, you must `return false` from your submit function. Otherwise your browser will handle it and redirect you to another page.

If you want to return an object from PHP, you must convert it to json using `json_encode`,
for example:

```
//PHP
$return = array("url" => "http://www.google.com");
echo json_encode($return);
//would echo something like {"url":"http://www.google.com"}

//JS
$.post(url, data, function(data){
  alert(data.url);
});
```

Comment: you can also apply the returned php data onto your page with $('#idOnMyPage').html(data.url) instead of alert(data.url);

Answer (score 0):

You have no ending `;`'s on functions.

Should be:

```
function changeMessage(message) {
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = message; 
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form").submit(function() {
        changeMessage("Checking");
        //check the username exists or not from ajax
        $.post("/stufftothink/php/AJAX/login.php",
               {user: $("#user").val(), pass:$("#pass").val() },
               function(result) {
              //if failed
              if (result === 'false') {
                        changeMessage("Invalid username or password. Check for typos and try again");
                    $("#pass").val("");
              }
              //if authenticated
              else {
                                changeMessage("Authenticatred");
                window.location.href = "/stufftothink/" +  result; 
              } 
       });
   });
});
```

Not sure if that'll fix it, but it's the only thing that jumps out at me.

Comment: Not fixing anything for me... :(

Comment: I don't think JavaScript requires `;`s after functions (or `if`s or `for`s or `while`s for that matter)...

Comment: Really? Hmmm, must just be bad practice to miss them out.